# How to sort post_meta in edit.php?

Tags: admin, post-meta, sort

I have Custom Type `cpt1` and Custom Fields `cf1`,
when you use hook `manage_cpt1-bien_sortable_columns`, wordpress don't sort the post_meta ?

Comment: There is a great hook to intercept $query, manipulate and ... : 'pre_get_posts'

function dotMastaz_set_myColumn_orderBy($query) {
 if (!is_admin()) return;

 $orderby = $query->get('orderby');

 if ('cf1' == $orderby) {
  $query->set('meta_key', 'cf1');
  $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
 }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'dotMastaz_set_myColumn_orderBy');

Comment: This is hard to follow. Is your comment additional details to the question or had you resolved it yourself?